# If $f$ is continuous real function such that $f(11) = 10$ and $\forall x, f(x)f(f(x)) = 1$ then find $f(9)$

Tags: functions

If $f$ is continuous real function such that $f(11) = 10$ and $\forall x, f(x)f(f(x)) = 1$, then $f(9) =$ ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

$f(11)=10$, so $f(11)f(10)=1$ and hence $f(10)=1/10$. But $f(x)$ is continuous, so $f(x_0)=9$ for some $10<x_0<11$. Hence $f(x_0)f(9)=1$, so $f(9)=1/9$.

Comment: Clear and concise.  +1